# draw a box and whisker plot for data divided into bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, boxplot

I have a dataframe with two columns (f1 and f2). You can create a sample dataframe using:

```
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'f1':[20,183,19,45,9173,11,482], 
        'f2':[771,8773,91,837,917,891,11]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
d = pd.DataFrame(data) 
  
# Print the output. 
d
```

I have divided the dataframe into 20 bins using the following code:

```
d['feature2'].value_counts(bins=20, sort=False)
```

However, the above mentioned line of code gives me the count in each bin. I want to split the dataframe into 20 bins and then draw box and whisker plot for each of the bin for both feature.

I know hexbin, hist2d have a parameter nbins:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, figsize=(21, 5))

nbins = 40
axes[0].set_title('Hexbin')
axes[0].hexbin(d.f1, d.f2, gridsize=nbins, cmap=plt.cm.BuGn_r)

# 2D Histogram
axes[1].set_title('2D Histogram')
axes[1].hist2d(d.f1, d.f2, bins=nbins, cmap=plt.cm.BuGn_r)
```

But it doesn't exist for Boxplot. Therefore, I want to divide my dataframe into 20 bins and for each bin I want to plot box and whisker plot for the two columns. How can I achieve that. Insights will be appreciated.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: `feature2` doesn't exist as a column in your dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what exactly is desired.

Here is a way to use Seaborn. First transform the dataframe to a "long" form, then create 20 bins for the values and finally create boxplots per feature:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

d = pd.DataFrame({'f1': np.random.rand(100, 100).cumsum(axis=0).ravel(),
                  'f2': np.random.rand(100, 100).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()})
dlong = d.melt(var_name='feature', value_name='value')
dlong['bins'] = pd.cut(dlong['value'], 20)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
sns.boxplot(data=dlong, x='bins', y='value', hue='feature', ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Here is a way to create two subplots using the same bins:

```py
d = pd.DataFrame({'f1': np.random.rand(100, 100).cumsum(axis=0).ravel(),
                  'f2': np.random.rand(100, 100).cumsum(axis=0).ravel()})
dlong = d.melt(var_name='feature', value_name='value')
dlong['bins'] = pd.cut(dlong['value'], 10)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12, 10))
sns.boxplot(data=dlong[dlong['feature'] =='f1' ], x='bins', y='value', ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(data=dlong[dlong['feature'] =='f2' ], x='bins', y='value', ax=ax2)
ax1.set_title('feature = f1')
ax2.set_title('feature = f2')
```

[image: two subplots]

Comment: this is exactly I want to do. Thanks! It's just my f1 is under f2. How can I make them segregate. I make 10 bins. I've put the image too.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But the bins became different for f1 and f2 and therefore, the two graphs weren't comparable.

Comment: You can use fixed bins, e.g. `bins=np.arange(min, max, step)` and `d['bins_f1'] = pd.cut(d['f1'], bins=bins)`. Fixed bins have the additional benefit that the bin edges are nicer numbers.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: I just did. Thank you :)